# Django: extend existing application/model with existing data

Tags: django, django-models

I have applications and models set up like the following.

Application A:

This application already has pre-populated data that will be used
by a few applications within the project, so I don't want to have
this data duplicated.

models.py

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country_code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country_name = models.ForeignKey(Countries)

class Cities(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country_name = models.ForeignKey(Countries)
    region_name = ChainedForeignKey(
        Regions,
        chained_field="country_name",
        chained_model_field="country_name",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=False,
    )
```

Application B:

I am looking to extend the models in Application A so that I can add
additional fields that will be used by the main part of the project.
I understand how to extend the models from Application A, but unsure
of how to do it correctly so that Application C works properly as well.
Only the extra fields should be in these tables. I don't want to duplicate
the data in Application A.

Application C - primary part of the project:

Here, I am wanting to use ForeignKey/ChainedForeignKey to select the location
and refine the location. Once you select the Country, it will only show you
the available Regions for that Country. Then once you have the Region selected
you will only see the Cities in those Regions. I've used ChainedForeignKey
before, so I am familiar with that.

The choices here should be based on the models in Application B. The Countries,
Regions and Cities will be enabled as needed.

What I currently have.
Application A is as shown above.

Application B:

```
class BaseLocation(models.Model):
    searchable = models.BooleanField('Searchable', default=True, help_text='Enables or Disables item for searching.')
    hidden = models.BooleanField('Hidden', help_text='Allows you to create searches without showing the item on the search page.')
    default = models.BooleanField('Default', help_text='Sets the default that will be used in forms.')
    enabled = models.BooleanField('Enabled', help_text="Enables or Disables item.", default=False)
    deprecated = models.BooleanField('Deprecated', help_text='Item should no longer be used.')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Country(BaseLocation):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, unique=True)

class Region(BaseLocation):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, to_field='country')
    region = ChainedForeignKey(
        Regions,
        chained_field='country',
        chained_model_field='country_name',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )

class City(BaseLocation):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, to_field='country')
    region = ChainedForeignKey(
        Regions,
        chained_field='country',
        chained_model_field='country_name',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )
    city = ChainedForeignKey(
        Cities,
        chained_field='region',
        chained_model_field='region_name',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )
```

Application C:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_listing = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, to_field='country')
    region = ChainedForeignKey(
        Region,
        chained_field='country',
        chained_model_field='country',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )
    city = ChainedForeignKey(
        City,
        chained_field='region',
        chained_model_field='region',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )
```

The problem with Application C is that I can do the lookup on the Country, but Region and City don't get populated when either referring to Application B or to A. I need it to use Application B because of the extra fields that are added to the models.

Not sure if what I am looking for can actually be done or not.

If anyone has any ideas on how this could be done, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. The issue was that I wasn't returning the correct value for the model for `__unicode__` but there was no clear error message until I tried the url that smartselect was using for the lookup.